# How to clear all TextField when begin editing or select TextField in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextfield

I have set up 4 TextFields and have connected them via `textFieldDidChange`. Now lets say I put in the wrong verification, I want to be able to select the `TextField` again and clear all last inputs. I tried `didBeginEditing` in Swift 3 but it doesn't work as it only clears one `TextField` not all four of the `TextField`. Please help.

```
import UIKit

class verificationVC: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var codefirstText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var codesecondText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var codethirdText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var codefourthText: UITextField!

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
    {
        codefirstText.text = ""
        codesecondText.text = ""
        codethirdText.text = ""
        codefourthText.text = ""

        if (codefirstText.text != nil)
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
        else if (codesecondText.text != nil)
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
        else if (codethirdText.text != nil)
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
        else if (codefourthText.text != nil)
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidChange (textfield: UITextField)
    {
        let text = textfield.text

        if text?.utf16.count == 1
        {
            switch textfield {
            case codefirstText:
                codesecondText.becomeFirstResponder()
            case codesecondText:
                codethirdText.becomeFirstResponder()
            case codethirdText:
                codefourthText.becomeFirstResponder()
            case codefourthText:
                codefourthText.resignFirstResponder()
            default:
                break
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you set `textfield` delegate methods to `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string can't be `nil` due to the sort of typing in Swift. Did you tried to control textfield values with empty string instead of `nil` value:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
    {
        codefirstText.text = ""
        codesecondText.text = ""
        codethirdText.text = ""
        codefourthText.text = ""

        if (codefirstText.text != "")
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
        else if (codesecondText.text != "")
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
        else if (codethirdText.text != "")
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }
        else if (codefourthText.text != "")
        {
            codefirstText.text = ""
            codesecondText.text = ""
            codethirdText.text = ""
            codefourthText.text = ""
        }

    }
```